# Colour averages within a specific range

Tags: python, jes

I want to change the white balance of an entire picture, using the average colours of pixels within a range determined by user input. I'm using variables called `startX`, `endX`, `startY` and `endY`.

I've managed to do it from a single pixel coordinate, but not from an averaged value of the pixels within the range. `greyValue` is where I get stuck because I don't know how to return the colour average.

```
def whiteBalanceBonus():
  File=pickAFile()
  myPict=makePicture(File)
  startX=requestInteger("Enter the value of the first 'X' Coordinate in the range")
  startY=requestInteger("Enter the value of the first 'Y' Coordinate in the range")
  endX=requestInteger("Enter the value of the last 'X' Coordinate in the range")
  endY=requestInteger("Enter the value of the last 'Y' Coordinate in the range")
  for x in range(startX,endX):
    for y in range(startY,endY):
      pixel=getPixel(myPict,x,y)
      greyValue=
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind solved it :)

```
def whiteBalanceBonus():
  File=pickAFile()
  myPict=makePicture(File)
  startX=requestInteger("Enter the value of the first 'X' Coordinate in the range")
  startY=requestInteger("Enter the value of the first 'Y' Coordinate in the range")
  endX=requestInteger("Enter the value of the last 'X' Coordinate in the range")
  endY=requestInteger("Enter the value of the last 'Y' Coordinate in the range")
  for x in range(startX,endX):
    for y in range(startY,endY):
      pixels=getPixel(myPict,x,y)
      greyValue=(getRed(pixels)+getGreen(pixels)+getBlue(pixels))/3
      redAdjust=(greyValue)/float(getRed(pixels))
      greenAdjust=(greyValue)/float(getGreen(pixels))
      blueAdjust=(greyValue)/float(getBlue(pixels))
  for px in getPixels(myPict):
    if (distance(white,getColor(px))>10):
      setRed(px,getRed(px)*redAdjust) 
      setGreen(px,getGreen(px)*greenAdjust)
      setBlue(px,getBlue(px)*blueAdjust)
  repaint (myPict)
```